# How in laravel with two routes under same middleware, after auth goes to their route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

This is my Route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/add', Add::class)->name('add');
    Route::get('/profile/{user}', Profile::class)->name('profile');
});
```

and the view has two links:

```
<a href="{{ route('add') }}">Add</a>
<a href="{{ route('profile', auth()->id()) }}">profile</a>
```

in the guest state, both links go to the login page, I want after login each route to be redirected to its destination automatically, something like this in the Login Auth function:

if request()->route or URL has "add"

```
return redirect()->to_route('add')
```

or something with another middleware.

?

Comment: That should happen automatically. Is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Laravel redirects intended method. Using the intended method after successful login it will redirect to the last page . if the user directly login then it goes to a specified route (here its the dashboard)

```
if(Auth::attempt(["email" => "", "password" =>""])){
                
   return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

> The intended method provided by Laravel's redirector will redirect the
> user to the URL they were attempting to access before being
> intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be
> given to this method in case the intended destination is not
> available.

Ref :https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: thank you. how about this route that has the parameter:
<a href="{{ route('profile', auth()->id()) }}">profile</a>. how add user()->id() in return redirect()->intended('dashboard') ?

Comment: if its a landing page without auth then definitely that URL will not have auth user id and will throw an error